# Passing Data between Views using Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I am making an App in which i **need to pass data between views** using *button click* in **Objective-C**.

I have created, **ViewController.m** to *pass* and **DetailController.m** to *get*...

**ViewController.m:**

```
   - (IBAction)btnSubmit:(id)sender {

     NSString *name = [txtName text];

     DetailController *view2 = [[[DetailController alloc] 
     initWithNibName:nil  bundle:nil] autorelease];
     [self presentViewController:view2 animated:NO completion:NULL];

      }
```

**DetailController.m**

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
     {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

        lblResult.text = [self.detailItem description];
      }
```

I am not getting the reason why i am not able to *pass name value to another view*

Comment: lblResult.text = self.detailItem if detailItem is a string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you **forgot to add** this line:

*view2.detailItem = name;*

```
      (IBAction)btnSubmit:(id)sender {

         NSString *name = [txtName text];

            DetailController *view2 = [[[DetailController alloc] 
            initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil] autorelease];
            view2.detailItem = name;
            [self presentViewController:view2 animated:NO completion:NULL];

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DetailController *view2 = [[[DetailController alloc] 
     initWithNibName:nil  bundle:nil] autorelease];
view2.detailItem = self.yourValue;    
[self presentViewController:view2 animated:NO completion:NULL];
```